# Unable to check infeasible constraints when using autodiff in PyDrake

Tags: python, drake

I am solving a problem in PyDrake with SNOPT and I get solutions that look reasonable, but when I do `result.is_success()` it comes back with `False`, so I am hoping to investigate why it thinks the problem wasn't solved. I assume I have a bad constraint somewhere, so I'm doing this with the following code:

```
result = mp.Solve(prog)
if not result.is_success():
    print("INFEASIBLE:")
    infeasible = result.GetInfeasibleConstraints(prog)
    for c in infeasible:
        print(c)
```

However, it exits on the call to `result.GetInfeasibleConstraints(prog)` with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_drake_distribution.py", line 250, in <module>
    infeasible = result.GetInfeasibleConstraints(prog)
  File "/home/adam/.miniconda3/envs/drake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydrake/solvers/_mathematicalprogram_extra.py", line 34, in _check_array_type
    f"{var_name} must be of scalar type {expected_name}, but unable "
RuntimeError: PyFunctionConstraint: Output must be of scalar type float, but unable to infer scalar type.
```

What it says is true, because my constraint functions are utilizing the autodiff functionality in Drake, so they are returning arrays with `dtype=AutoDiffXd`. If this is the case, does that mean I cannot use the constraint infeasibility checker? Any advice on being able to check infeasible constraints when I'm using autodiff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you write your constraint using a python function. I would suggest to write this python function to handle both float and autodiffxd, so something like this

```py
def my_evaluator(x: np.ndarray):
    if x.dtype == np.object:
        # This is the autodiff case
    elif x.dtype == np.float:
        # This is the float case
```

Comment: Does that mean it's being evaluated differently when it's being solved from when the constraints are being checked? In terms of the input/output types, that is.

Comment: Thanks Hongkai, this led me in the right direction. As part of my constraint I was creating an array like `a = np.zeros(N, dtype=AutoDiffXd)` and populating it. I changed it to `a = np.zeros(N, dtype=x.dtype)` where `x` is the input array to the constraint function, that did the trick.

Comment: When we solve the optimization problem, we evaluate the constraints with autodiff scalars, so as to obtain the constraint gradient, to be used in gradient-based solver (SNOPT/IPOPT/NLOPT). When we check the feasibility, we only need the constraint value, not its gradient, so we re-evaluate it using double.